# Using Laplace to solve pure death process

Tags: stochastic-processes, birth-death-process

I have got all differential equations as shown below in the image, but I don't know how to proceed next to solve.
In hint, it was given that you can use Laplace to solve it.
Can someone show me how to do that. 
[image]